# My function returns a struct; why is assignment to a field of that result value disallowed by the compiler?

Tags: function, go, struct, field, assign

In golang, if I return a struct type in a function, I got compilation error, I have to use the pointer of struct as the return type to achieve member access directly via the function call. Why is that? Doesn't foo() return a temporary variable of type Employee?

```
package main


type Employee struct {
ID int
Name string
Address string
Position string
Salary int
ManagerID int
}
var dilbert Employee


func foo() Employee {
    employee := Employee{}
    return employee
}

func bar() *Employee {
    employee := Employee{}
    return &employee
}

func main() {
    dilbert.Salary = 1
    var b = foo()
    b.Salary = 1

    bar().Salary = 1    // this is good
    foo().Salary = 1    // this line has the compilation error cannot assign to foo().Salary
}
```

Comment: `foo()` is a struct _value_, but not a struct _variable_ (i.e. addressable value). You can only modify the fields of a struct variable, not those of a struct value. By contrast, `bar().Salary` is legal, because it's actually syntactic sugar for `(*bar()).Salary`, and `*bar()` is a variable (since you can obtain its address, which is simply `bar()`).

Comment: @jub0bs so essentially there is no temp variable created for function return value in golang? (unlike C++)

Comment: I don't know about C++ but Go doesn't automatically create a variable for return values, no. Note that, if you introduce a variable (`f := foo()`), then `f.Salary = 1` is legal.

Comment: actually I meant to say Java. C++ cannot work either since the function return type is not a lvalue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, a [*variable*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) is addressable, i.e. a value of which you can obtain the address. Assignments are valid if the left-hand side is addressable.

`bar().Salary = 1` is legal because

1. `bar().Salary` is actually syntactic sugar for `(*bar()).Salary`;
2. `*bar()` is addressable because it's a pointer indirection;
3. fields (e.g. `Salary`) of addressable structs are themselves addressable

By contrast, `foo().Salary = 1` is illegal because `foo()` returns a value, but it is *not* a variable nor a pointer indirection; there is no way of obtaining `foo()`'s address. That explains why that statement is rejected by the compiler. Note that introducing an intermediate variable solves your problem:

```golang
// type and function declarations omitted

func main() {
    f := foo()
    f.Salary = 1 // compiles fine
}
```

Answer (score 3):

foo() returns a 'value' of struct type and we can not assign anything to a value.
While bar() returns a pointer to a variable. We can use this pointer to assign a different value to this variable

This error isn't essentially related to struct but with assigning value to a value. Consider the following example:

```
func retint() int{
    var a int=5
    return a
}

func retintp() *int{
    var a int=5
    return &a
}
func main(){
    print("hello")
    *retintp()=10   // this is valid as we can store 10 to address pointed by a
    retint()=10     // this gives error. as we can not assign 10 to 5

}
```

Here retint() returns a value (5). we can not assign anything to 5 but retintp() returns address of variable a. We can use this address to assign a value to it

Comment: There _are_ no references in Go. A pointer is not a reference. It should read "While bar() returns a pointer to a variable. We can use this pointer to assign a different value to this variable."

Comment: Thanks for pointing this @volker . I have modified the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
bar().Salary = 1
```

Returns a pointer and we are writing to the object pointed to by the pointer

```
foo().Salary = 1
```

foo() returns a temporary object, and since we are not storing it anywhere, the temporary object would be lost if not assigned to a variable. Hence go compiler is complaining

Following will work

```
f = foo()
f.Salary = 1
```